# Laravel save related data in database

Tags: laravel, save

I want to save question_id in answer table using post form

I tried to use foreach or functions but i always got null data

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey)
{
    $request->validate([
        'answer' => 'required',
    ]);

    $survey->option_name = unserialize($survey->option_name);

    $answers = new Answer([
        'answer' => $request->get('answer'),
        'commentaire' => $request->get('commentaire'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'last_ip' => request()->ip(),
        'question_id' => $survey->questions,
        'survey_id' => $survey->id,
    ]);

    $answers->save();

    return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
}
```

answers table [image: answers table]
question table's row :

- id
- survey_id
- title
- timestamp

I got always null data or i tried using where but i got errors like id index doesn't exists...

Comment: Please describe the `survey` table

Comment: Hello , Survey table : `id` , `title` ,`description`, `user_id` (for the poster not user answered for survey)

Comment: `$survey->questions` returns a collection, not an id.  Are you trying to save one answer or multiple answers?  Please add your front end code.

Comment: Posted sir in the answer's area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View :

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>array('AnswerController@store', $survey->id))) !!}
          @forelse ($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
            <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $key+1 }} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="answer" type="text" name="answer">
                    <label for="answer">Answer</label>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]"></textarea>
                    <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      @if($value === 'else')
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <input name="answer" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="{{ $value }}" value="{{$value}}"/>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                        <div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
                            <br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="commentaire" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Write a large text here ..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        @else
                      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <input name="answer" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="{{ $value }}" value="{{ $value}}"/>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                        @endif
                  @endforeach
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $value }}" name="answer" value="{{$value}}"/>
                      <label for="{{$value}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                      </div>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                @endif 
              <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
          @empty
            <span class='flow-text center-align'>Nothing to show</span>
            @endempty
          <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Survey', array('class'=>'btn btn-success mt-4')) }}
          </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```